# Multiple Indexes: one index for every part of the book

Tags: imakeidx

I'm working on a book project which is divided in several parts. Basically at the end of every part I want an index. The index should only lists these words which are mentioned in this part. What is the easiest way to realise this?

In my MWE below you can see what I tried so far. I want the following:

- INDEX 1 should list *Aaa*, *Bbb* and *Ccc*
- INDEX 2 should list *Aaa*, *Ddd* and *Eee*

In my "solution" INDEX 2 lists the same as INDEX 1.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex


\begin{document}

\part{My Headline}

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \index{Aaa}\index{Bbb}\index{Caa} % keywords for INDEX 1

    \printindex % INDEX 1

\part{Two}

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Eee} % keywords for INDEX 2

    \printindex % INDEX 2

\end{document}
```

**What I don't want**

I know about `splitidx`. In the manual it says:

> Separate indices are declared and given unique shortcut identiers with
>   the \newindex command.

My question is: Is there a way to avoid the `\nexindex` command? The book is already written and I don't want to change for example `\index{Aaa}` to `\newindex{index1}{Aaa}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeindex[name=index1]

\makeindex[name=index2]


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\latex@@index\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
  \latex@@index[index\number\value{part}]{#1}%
}
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\part{My Headline}

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \index{Aaa}\index{Bbb}\index{Caa} % keywords for INDEX 1

    \printindex[index\number\value{part}] % INDEX 1

\part{Two}

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Eee} % keywords for INDEX 2

    \printindex[index\number\value{part}] % INDEX 2

\end{document}
```

**Improved version**

Automatically defined `\makeindex[index...]` in a loop and `\printindex`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\setupindexfiles}[1]{%
\setcounter{loopcntr}{1}%
\loop\unless\ifnum\value{loopcntr}>#1%
\makeindex[name=index\number\value{loopcntr}]
\stepcounter{loopcntr}%
\repeat
}%




\setupindexfiles{3}


\AtBeginDocument{%
\LetLtxMacro\latex@@index\index
\LetLtxMacro\latex@@printindex\printindex
\renewcommand{\index}[2][]{%
  \def\first@arg{#1}%
  \ifx\first@arg\empty
  \latex@@index[index\number\value{part}]{#2}%
  \else
  \latex@@index[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\printindex}[1][]{%
  \def\first@arg{#1}%
  \ifx\first@arg\empty
  \latex@@printindex[index\number\value{part}]%
  \else
  \latex@@printindex[#1]%
  \fi
}
}


\makeatother


\begin{document}

\part{My Headline}

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \index{Aaa}\index{Bbb}\index{Caa} % keywords for INDEX 1

    \printindex

\part{Two}

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Eee} % keywords for INDEX 2

    \printindex%




\part{Three}

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \index{Aaa}\index{FFFFFF}\index{AAAAAAA} % keywords for INDEX 2

    \printindex%



\end{document}
```

Comment: A first version, I will update

Comment: Thanks so far. How can I modify your solution if we're talking about this situation: INDEX 1 should list all keywords of CHAPTER 1 AND 2 and INDEX 2 should list all keywords of CHAPTER 3 TO 5?

Comment: @Sr.Schneider: That's a question change, actually. That's not in your post above and I did not address this!

Comment: @Christan: Should I ask this separately?

Comment: @Sr.Schneider: Of course!

Comment: You can find my follow-up question here: [Multiple Indexes: one index for one or more chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322170/multiple-indexes-one-index-for-one-or-more-chapters)