# Conditionals: \renewcommand{\index}

Tags: environments, conditionals, imakeidx

I'm working on a book project which is divided in several parts and chapters. At the end of some chapters (let's say at the end of chapter 2 and 3) I want an index which lists all the keyword mentioned since the last index.

**The output should look like this**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=1]
\makeindex[name=2]

\begin{document}

\part{My Headline}

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \index[1]{Aaa}\index[1]{Bbb}\index[1]{Caa} % keywords for INDEX 1

    \chapter{My Headline}
    \blindtext[2]

    \index[1]{Aaa}\index[1]{Ddd}\index[1]{Eee} % keywords for INDEX 1

    \printindex[1] % INDEX 1

    \chapter{My Headline}

    \index[2]{Aaa}\index[2]{Ddd}\index[2]{Fff} % keywords for INDEX 2

    \printindex[2] % INDEX 2

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the book is already written and I don't want to change all `\index{}` commands to `\index[1]{}` or `\index[2]{}` manually. The idea is to redefine the `\index{}` command depending on the chapter number.

**I'm looking for something like:**

```
\if \thechapter < 3
    \renewcommand{\index}{\index[1]}
\else
    \renewcommand{\index}{\index[2]}
\fi
```

*The code above doesn't work and I don't know why.*

**My file looks now like this**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=1]
\makeindex[name=2]

% here is something missing like:
%
% \if \thechapter < 3
%   \renewcommand{\index}{\index[1]}
% \else
%   \renewcommand{\index}{\index[2]}
% \fi

\renewcommand{\index}

\begin{document}

\part{My Headline}

        \chapter{My Headline}
        \blindtext[2]

        \index{Aaa}\index{Bbb}\index{Caa} % keywords for INDEX 1

        \chapter{My Headline}
        \blindtext[2]

        \index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Eee} % keywords for INDEX 1

        \printindex[1] % INDEX 1

        \chapter{My Headline}

        \index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Fff} % keywords for INDEX 2

        \printindex[2] % INDEX 2

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your approach is syntactically and logically wrong: `\if \thechapter` can't work and even if it would work, at the time of writing the command it does not what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a code similar to the other answer to a question by the OP I provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322161/multiple-indexes-one-index-for-every-part-of-the-book)

First grab the original definition of `\index`, taking care of the optional argument introduced by `imakeidx` and then branching into the original version if `\index[...]{foo}` is used or checking for the chapter number with

```
\ifnum\value{chapter} < 3
\else
\fi
```

Of course, this does work for this particular purpose only.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=1]
\makeindex[name=2]

\makeatletter

\LetLtxMacro\latex@@index\index
\renewcommand{\index}[2][]{%
  \def\@firstarg{#1}%
  \ifx\@firstarg\empty
  \ifnum\value{chapter} < 3
  \latex@@index[1]{#2}%
  \else
  \latex@@index[2]{#2}%
  \fi
  \else
  \latex@@index[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{My Headline}

\chapter{My Headline}
\blindtext[2]

\index{Aaa}\index{Bbb}\index{Caa} % keywords for INDEX 1

\chapter{My Headline}
\blindtext[2]

\index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Eee} % keywords for INDEX 1

\printindex[1] % INDEX 1

\chapter{My Headline}

\index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Fff} % keywords for INDEX 2

\printindex[2] % INDEX 2

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the default value for the optional argument into the current chapter number.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}

\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,noclearpage}

\makeindex[name=1,intoc]
\makeindex[name=2,intoc]
\makeindex[name=3,intoc]

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
% The default value for the optional argument is the jobname.
% Change it into the current chapter number.
\renewcommand{\index}{%
  \@bsphack
  \@ifnextchar[{\@index}{\@index[\arabic{chapter}]}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{My Headline}

\chapter{My Headline}
\blindtext[2]

\index{Aaa}\index{Bbb}\index{Caa} % keywords for INDEX 1

\printindex[2] % INDEX 1

\chapter{My Headline}
\blindtext[2]

\index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Eee} % keywords for INDEX 2

\printindex[2] % INDEX 2

\chapter{My Headline}

\index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Fff} % keywords for INDEX 3

\printindex[3] % INDEX 3

\end{document}
```

I also added the necessary bits in order for the local indices to be printed correctly. The `noautomatic` option is mandatory, because otherwise the index files will be closed upon processing the first `\printindex` command.

[image]

For a sequence of indices not tied to chapters, a different strategy can be used: we define a counter that's stepped at each printing of an index and use that instead of the `chapter` counter like in the previous solution.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}

\indexsetup{
  othercode={\stepcounter{printindex}},
}

\makeindex[name=1,intoc]
\makeindex[name=2,intoc]

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
% The default value for the optional argument is the jobname.
% Change it into the current printindex value, that's stepped
% at each \printindex command.
\newcounter{printindex}
\setcounter{printindex}{1}
\renewcommand{\index}{%
  \@bsphack
  \@ifnextchar[{\@index}{\@index[\arabic{printindex}]}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{My Headline}

\chapter{My Headline}
\blindtext[2]

\index{Aaa}\index{Bbb}\index{Caa} % keywords for INDEX 1

\chapter{My Headline}
\blindtext[2]

\index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Eee} % keywords for INDEX 2

\printindex[1] % INDEX 1

\chapter{My Headline}

\index{Aaa}\index{Ddd}\index{Fff} % keywords for INDEX 3

\printindex[2] % INDEX 2

\end{document}
```

A picture of the first index:

[image]

Comment: In your solution it's possible to combine the keywords for chapter 1 and 2 in one index at the end of chapter 2?

Comment: @Sr.Schneider Of course not. I'll make another one. But I can't see what could be a reason for this.